# how to show loading screen till the asynctask is done loading

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, loading

Here is the code for the activity ,what creates the problem is the while loop it blocks the ui thread but it halts the conrol till the loading is done ,what i want is to show some image till the asynctask is done is task if success then screen1 else screen2.what currently i see is just black screen.
Plz help.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class loadingscreen extends Activity {


public final static String UID_MESSAGE="abe user name hai be";
int al=0,rt=0;

public static Spinner pb;
SharedPreferences save;
TelephonyManager tel;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
networker create;

String def=null;
String newt=null;
String imei=null;
String bus="AA";
Context context;
Intent  intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                    
    save=getSharedPreferences("map",MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor=save.edit(); 
    tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);        
    setContentView(R.layout.loading);
    pb=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.pb);

    def=save.getString("uid","test");
    imei=tel.getDeviceId();       


    if(!(def.equals("true"))){

            Log.e(null," please wait logging in ");         

            new fsnetworker(context,0,0,0,5).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,imei,def,bus);

            while(fsnetworker.done==0){ Log.e(null,"trying "); }

            if(fsnetworker.done==4 ){                       

                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MapActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(UID_MESSAGE, def);                                
                startActivity(intent);                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            }       
    }


    intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),firstScreen.class);
    intent.putExtra(UID_MESSAGE, def);                                
    startActivity(intent);   

}   


public static class fsnetworker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

Context context;                 
double lat=0f;
double lng=0f;  
float acc=0;
int rt=0;
String imei;
String uid;
String bus;
public static int done;

public fsnetworker(Context context,double lat2,double lng2,float acc2,int rt){

this.context=context;
this.lat=lat2;
this.lng=lng2;
this.acc=acc2;
this.rt=rt;

}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
 super.onPreExecute();


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String success) {
 super.onPostExecute(success);


}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    try{ 
         done=0;
         Log.e(null,"networking");
         imei=(String)arg0[0];
         uid=(String)arg0[1];
         bus=(String)arg0[2];


        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpGet get=new HttpGet();
           get.setURI(new URI("http://*********************?"
                     +"imei="+imei
                     +"&name="+uid
                     +"&lat="+lat
                     +"&lng="+lng
                     +"&acc="+acc
                     +"&bus="+bus
                     +"&rt="+rt));

           HttpResponse response=client.execute(get);
           HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();

           BufferedReader sread=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
           StringBuilder  sb = new StringBuilder();
           String out=null;
           while((out=sread.readLine())!=null){
               sb.append(out);
               break;
           }

         Log.e(" url", ""+sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to track the current status of your AsyncTask. You can can identify when your AsyncTask is finished, When AsyncTask finished its task it will call the onPostExecute method.

Your modified code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class loadingscreen extends Activity {


public final static String UID_MESSAGE="abe user name hai be";
int al=0,rt=0;

public static Spinner pb;
SharedPreferences save;
TelephonyManager tel;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
networker create;

String def=null;
String newt=null;
String imei=null;
String bus="AA";
Context context;
Intent  intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                    
    save=getSharedPreferences("map",MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor=save.edit(); 
    tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);        
    setContentView(R.layout.loading);
    pb=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.pb);

    def=save.getString("uid","test");
    imei=tel.getDeviceId();       


    if(!(def.equals("true"))){

            Log.e(null," please wait logging in ");         

            new fsnetworker(context,0,0,0,5).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,imei,def,bus);
  
    }


    intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),firstScreen.class);
    intent.putExtra(UID_MESSAGE, def);                                
    startActivity(intent);   

}   


public static class fsnetworker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

Context context;                 
double lat=0f;
double lng=0f;  
float acc=0;
int rt=0;
String imei;
String uid;
String bus;
public static int done;

public fsnetworker(Context context,double lat2,double lng2,float acc2,int rt){

this.context=context;
this.lat=lat2;
this.lng=lng2;
this.acc=acc2;
this.rt=rt;

}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
 super.onPreExecute();


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String success) {
 super.onPostExecute(success);

intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MapActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(UID_MESSAGE, def);                                
                startActivity(intent);

}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    try{ 
         done=0;
         Log.e(null,"networking");
         imei=(String)arg0[0];
         uid=(String)arg0[1];
         bus=(String)arg0[2];


        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpGet get=new HttpGet();
           get.setURI(new URI("http://*********************?"
                     +"imei="+imei
                     +"&name="+uid
                     +"&lat="+lat
                     +"&lng="+lng
                     +"&acc="+acc
                     +"&bus="+bus
                     +"&rt="+rt));

           HttpResponse response=client.execute(get);
           HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();

           BufferedReader sread=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
           StringBuilder  sb = new StringBuilder();
           String out=null;
           while((out=sread.readLine())!=null){
               sb.append(out);
               break;
           }

         Log.e(" url", ""+sb.toString());
```

Comment: How am i suppose to go to map activity?

Comment: See the onPostExecute method

Comment: I m still getting error, may be i shall remove static from async class

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to get AsyncTasks.  They execute in parallel.  So you do NOT put code that you want to execute after its done after calling execute.  You put it in the onPostExecute function, which is called on the UI thread after the task has completed.  You NEVER loop, sleep, or otherwise wait until an AsyncTask is done-  that's against the entire point.

Comment: So what according to u shall i do,this is working correctly i just need to show a loading screen till it finishes.

Comment: Take everything that you want to happen after the task finishes.  Put it in onPostExecute.  Remove the loop.  Unless you do that your app will not display any changes until the task finishes.  And it will crash on most phones if the task is non-trivial, due to tripping the watchdog timer on the UI thread.

Comment: I want to start a new activity but startActivity(); cannot be called there.

Comment: Yes it can.  You just need to pass the AsyncTask a context to call it on, generally in the constructor.

Comment: You pass it in an *instance* of a Context-  like your Activity is an instance of Context.  This is pretty basic Java-  startActivity is not a magic keyword, its a function you're calling.  It behaves like any other functions.